# How to efficiently retrieve a specific class property value with similar named string as of property name

Tags: c#, object

I have a class structure for an example as below

```
public class ColorStuff
        {
            public Red Red { get; set; }
            public Green Green { get; set; }
            public Blue Blue { get; set; }
        }

public class Red
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

public class Green
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

public class Blue
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }
```

I have a method as below to retrieve color Id by the color name as below

```
public string GetColorIdByName(string colorName)
        {
            var colorSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ColorStuff>(content);
            string colorId = string.Empty;
            switch (colorName)
            {
                case "Red":
                    colorId = colorSettings.Red.Id;
                    break;
                case "Green":
                    colorId = colorSettings.Green.Id;
                    break;
                case "Blue":
                    colorId = colorSettings.Blue.Id;
                    break;
            }

            return colorId;
        }
```

As you can see that for each color name I have to create a switch case. Is there by anyway I can call without multiple switch case?

Since for example if I want to retrieve color Id for 'Green' I access the 'Green' class and it's associated property. Instead of keeping separate switch case, is there any other efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: you *could* use reflection, but frankly the `switch` is more readable and **much** more efficient; the main change there that I'd make would be to use a "switch expression" in C# 8: `return colorName switch { "Red" => colorSettings.Red.Id, "Green" => colorSettings.Green.Id, "Blue" => colorSettings.Blue.Id, _ => ""}` - although I'd probably also change to use the same type for all 3 (there's no need for separate `Red`/`Green`/`Blue` types in the code shown (I might also use `nameof`, but... meh)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell. This looks bit better than what i've done if I end up with less number of cases

Answer (score 1):

You could make use Reflection for the purpose. For example,

```
var color = GetPropertyValue(colorSettings, colorName);
var id = GetPropertyValue(color, "Id");
```

Or

```
var id = GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(colorSettings, colorName), "Id");
```

Where `GetPropertyValue` is defined as

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object instance ,string propertyName)
{
    var objType = instance.GetType();
    var prop = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    return prop.GetValue(instance, null);
}
```